# CRAN submission fine on Linux, fails on Win-builder

Tags: r, windows, package, cran, vignette

I am in the process of submitting a package to CRAN. I did the --as-cran check on Linux which run through cleanly except for one note for the CRAN incoming feasibility . I believe that this note belongs to the message "new submission" because I cannot see any other additional message. The status is OK. When I submit to CRAN I get errors on Windows related to vignette building.
Check: re-building of vignette outputs, Result: WARNING
  Error(s) in re-building vignettes:
  --- re-building 'vignette-testme.Rmd' using rmarkdown

The stack trace for the error on Windows is difficult to interpret as the failure occurs at a point where the setup has worked fine. I have prepared the .tar.gz file as follows:

1. From the git repository I pulled the latest version using 'git archive --format tar HEAD'
2. I used "R CMD build xyz" to build the package
3. I performed "R CMD check --as-cran xyz_version.tar.gz" on the resulting archive
4. I uploaded this file to CRAN

Did I forget a necessary step? The package is pure R code. I have uploaded the offending file to https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nbe-8Os2MhI-O75IYNT0ZKQMonfZsynx (beware, code drom the internet) in case you want to have a look.

I have to tried to manually install on windows using Rstudio. I also get an error during vignette-building, this time in the setup phase:

Warning in file.create(to[okay]) :

cannot create file '\vf-home/home$/bs/MyDocs/R/win-library/3.6/00LOCK-testme/00new/testme/doc/vignette-testme.R', reason 'No such file or directory'

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Why are you submitting to CRAN without checking on Windows? Use https://win-builder.r-project.org/ and link to the result in this question. A link to your git repository would be useful.

Comment: win-builder.r-project.org is exactly what is used during CRAN submission

Comment: No, it's not. It's a helpful service but independent of CRAN submission. If you already use it, you should be able to provide a link to the check results.

Comment: I have run on https://win-builder.r-project.org and the package passes with identical output to what is produced under linux. I have pinged the CRAN maintainers about this problem.